# Scroll View Positioning in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

I have a requirement to produce a scroll view in Flutter in which a widget containing content needs to be scrollable over top of a header widget. The header should be part of the background of the container and the content should be scrollable to cover the header. The image below illustrates this. The view on the left shows the default view when the widget is loaded. The view on the right shows the desired behavior when the view is scrolled upward to cover the header view. I've looked into `SingleChildScrollView` but can't find any properties that allow me to offset the content at the bottom. Can anyone suggest a different widget or point to a resource that might help? THanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below shows how you can create such feature.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: kToolbarHeight * 6,
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                '[32] Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum[d] exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? [D]Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? [33] At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```